# How can I get the call stack in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have a point in my clojure code where I want to know what the call stack was (ie: list of clojure functions used to get there). How can I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This isn't the nicest solution, but it's simple and it should work in core clojure:

```
(try (throw (Exception. "")) (catch Exception e (.printStackTrace e *out*)))
```

You can inspect e in code if you want something other than a printed version. See also clojure.stacktrace in the current master branch or clj-stacktrace for clojure 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

`clojure.repl` contains `pst`.

Example:

```
(pst (Exception. "") nr-lines
```